# htaccess more than one file rewriting to root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site setup with `php` scripts in a `/pages/` folder which rewrites:

`www.example.com/pages/settings.php`

...to...

`www.example.com/settings`

Using this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA]
```

But I would also like users profiles to redirect too:

`www.exmaple.com/user123`

Now I'm not sure what the best approach to this would be as I also have pages redirecting to root.

I have a `user.php` which pulls in the user data depending on what `GET` variable is in the `url`:

`(www.exmaple.com/pages/user.php?username=user123)`

But I was wondering if this was possible to rewrite to root with `htaccess` as well as the initial page rewrite?

I have tried to do stuff like this but I have not yet got it to work properly:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /pages/user.php?username=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /pages/user.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to duplicate your rules. You can use `/?` for an optional slash at the end

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA]
```

same with

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /pages/user.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

These rules allow for a request with or without a trailing slash.

To your question, I don't see how you can accomplish this, because you want to rewrite the same string to two different targets. If there is no prefix or a unique string distinguishing a user from an action request, you cannot do that.

You can rewrite `/user/user123` with this rule

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /pages/user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You must put this rule before the action rule, because the action rule has the more general matching pattern.

I would also prefix the action rule with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to prevent real files, like `index.php`, `user.php`, css, javascript or image files, being rewritten.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't suppose you can suggest a better method of handling users profiles? Maybe something like `/user/user123`?